# How to change language in ew:calendarpopup?

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

Tried searching online, but seems that nobody use ew:calendarpopup on .NET? Maybe deprecated?
Well, I just need to put language English and German on this calendar.

For italian, just done Language="Italy" :

```
<ew:calendarpopup id="Arrive" width="160" runat="server" ControlDisplay="TextBoxImage" ImageUrl="~/privat/images.png" DateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" Language="<%=m_strCalendarLanguage %>">
```

and it seems to works.

But with english and german, not! Neither using Culture="".

Do you know how to do this on .NET 3.5+? Thanks

## EDIT

What I tried (on client side) :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Culture="en-GB" %>
```

What I tried (on server side) :

```
// adding  EnableScriptGlobalization="true" on ScriptManager
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

But nothing...the calendar's language is always "italian"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this Excentrics World control?
if so Culture="de-DE" works for me

Comment: Also tried on write this on <%@ Page Language="C#" Culture="en-GB" %> but nothing....

Comment: i currently this use in a page `<%@ Register Assembly="eWorld.UI, Version=2.0.6.2393, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24d65337282035f2"
    Namespace="eWorld.UI" TagPrefix="ew" %>` and this as an example control `<ew:CalendarPopup id="cldArticleExpiryDate" runat="server" ControlDisplay="TextBoxImage"
                     DisableTextBoxEntry="False" ImageUrl="/includes/images/date.png" Culture="de-DE"
                     ShowGoToToday="true"></ew:CalendarPopup>`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but this should work:

- English (United Kingdom)
- German (Germany)